# How feasible it is to add columns in Redshift once it has too much data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I think Redshift as Relational Database. I am having one scenario which I wanted to know:-

If there is an existing redshift database, then how easy or how much time it would take to add a column? Does it take a lock on the table when added a new field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Redshift is a columnar database. This means each column is stored separately on disk, which is why it operates so quickly.

Adding a column is therefore a relatively simple operation.

If you are worried about it, you could use the [`CREATE TABLE AS` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html) to create a new table based on the current one, then add a column and see how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Like any rdmbs column will be added in the order of entry. i.e it with the last columns (not in the middle or whereever you like)